# CKeditor5 - plugin - widget - state

Tags: plugins, widget, ckeditor, state, ckeditor5

I am (re)writing a plugin for CK editor 5.
In version 4 i added HTML like this:

`<span data-id="my-special-value" class="my-widget">My label</span>`

I need the data-id value in PHP to do my stuff. But i can not figure out how to accomplish this in CKeditor 5.

CKeditor 5 works differently. It is very beautiful, but i still can`t find out how to add a widget like this with additional state (the data-id attribute).

I tried:

```
const viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView(html);
const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
editor.model.insertContent( modelFragment );
```

My very basic conversioncode:

```js
model.schema.register(pluginSlug, {
    isBlock: false,
    isObject: true,
    allowContentOf: '$block',
    allowWhere: [ '$block', '$text'],
});

// Retrieving the data from the editor.
editor.conversion.for('dataDowncast').add( downcastElementToElement( {
    model: pluginSlug,
    view: (modelItem, writer) => {
        const element = writer.createContainerElement( 'span', { class: 'widget form-element-wysiwyg', test: "test" });

        return element;
    }
}) );

// Rendering the editor content to the user for editing.
editor.conversion.for('editingDowncast').add( downcastElementToElement( {
    model: pluginSlug,
    view: (modelItem, writer) => {
        const element = writer.createContainerElement('span', { class: 'widget form-element-wysiwyg', test: "test" });
        const widget = toWidget( element, writer, { label: 'Target Label' });

        return widget;
    }
}) );

// Loading the data to the editor.
editor.conversion.for('upcast').add( upcastElementToElement( {
    view: {
        name: 'span',
        class: 'widget form-element-wysiwyg'
    },
    model: pluginSlug
}) );
```

I really can`t find out how to manage this. This code tries to add:
`<span data-id="my-special-value" class="my-widget">My label</span>`
but now it still adds:
`<span class="my-widget">My label</span>`

As you will see, it actually adds: 
`<span class="my-widget" test="test">My label</span>`
because of the dataDowncast code, but how to get my state from the insertContent code part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of quick advices:

1. This is incorrect: `allowWhere: [ '$block', '$text']`. You can't have a single element behaving like a block and like a text. You need to choose one – it's either inline or block.
2. Seeing that you use `<span>` I guess "inline" is a better choice. In CKEditor 5 v12.0.0 (released a couple of days ago) we introduced support for inline widgets. Check out the [implementing inline widget guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html) which covers a couple of things that you will need to know – especially the schema.
3. In the upcast converter you have `view.class`. This is incorrect – there's only `view.classes`. Plus, if you want to match against multiple classes you need to use an array. See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcasthelpers-UpcastHelpers.html#function-elementToElement and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_matcher-MatcherPattern.html
4. In CKEditor v12.0.0 the `downcastElementToElement()` and `upcastElementToElement()` methods were moved to a different place in the document. Read more in [the migration guide](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1582).

Finally, the solution to how to upcast `data-id` and store in the model is that the upcast converter needs to set it on the model element. Check out this example from [`UpcastHelpers#elementToElement()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcasthelpers-UpcastHelpers.html#function-elementToElement):

```
editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToElement( {
    view: {
        name: 'p',
        classes: 'heading'
    },
    model: ( viewElement, modelWriter ) => {
        return modelWriter.createElement( 'heading', { level: viewElement.getAttribute( 'data-level' ) } );
    }
} );
```

As you can see, the `model` part can be a callback returning a model element. It has access to the view element so you can read the attributes you need.

You can also do the same thing using [`UpcastHelpers#elementToElement()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcasthelpers-UpcastHelpers.html#function-elementToElement) and then [`UpcastHelpers#attributeToAttribute()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcasthelpers-UpcastHelpers.html#function-attributeToAttribute) separately.

Comment: Thanks for this great awnser. Didnt noticed yet the new version.

I had to add the allowAttributes, then it works as a charm!